# How can I tell Perl's IO::Socket::INET which interface to use?

Tags: perl, interface, sockets

I have two interfaces on my server, eth0 and eth0:0. Those are two different external IP addresses and obviously two different reverse domains.

When I open a IO::Socket::INET connection, Perl uses the eth0 interface by default. I would like to use the second interface (eth0:0) because this has a different IP and I dont want to use my main IP or domain.

I have absolutely no idea how to select which interface to connect through.

Here's the code I use to open a socket:

```
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr    => $server,
                                PeerPort    => $serverPort,
                                Proto       => 'tcp') or
                             die "Can't connect to server: $!";
```

Comment: The server (which you don't show) binds to an interface (or all interfaces) with a LocalAddr parameter. The client should use the address of the interface it wants to talk to.

Answer (score 9):

You have to give [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Socket::INET) the address of the interface you want to use as `LocalAddr` parameter. Imagine that `10.0.0.1` is the IP address of eth0 and `10.0.0.2` the IP address of eth0:0, then it would work like this.

```
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr    => $server,
    PeerPort    => $serverPort,
    Proto       => 'tcp'
    LocalAddr   => '10.0.0.2') or
  die "Can't connect to server: $!";
```

Comment: There is not such thing as "the IP address of the interface". The OS routing mechanism will determine which interface to use for a given IP. Your answer does not make any sense.